# Quotation Marks disappearing in pandas read csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So, I have a .txt file and I want to read it in pandas.
The line is this when I open in Notepad++:

```
"1013764";"Test INT"12345678"";"TEST";"TEST";""
```

Then, to open in pandas, I do this:

```
data = pd.read_csv("TestFile.TXT", sep=";")
```

When I print "data", it appears like this:

[image]

Any solution for the quotation mark not to disappear?

Comment: The quotation marks are part of the format, not of the actual data. If you don't want to parse the data as CSV, you can read it as a regular text file; CSV is just a text format with additional contstraints and conventions.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: I "solved it" changing the code to data = pd.read_csv("TestFile.TXT", sep=";", quotechar = '`'). This is not the best solution, so if anyone has any better solution, I thank you!

Comment: Again, don't use a CSV parser if you don't want to parse the data as CSV.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the quotation marks by replacing them.
Let's say that the column name is col1, then:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.replace('/"', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I could find is

```py
import csv
import pandas

data = pd.read_csv("<youre file>", sed=";", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

(In your case the code above will produce this:
`Columns: ["1013764", "Test INT"12345678"", "TEST", "TEST", ""]`)

The Problem with this is that read_csv will parse everything as a string. I would advise you (If you want to preserve the "datatypes") to use diffrent quotes in your csv (like ') to signal to pandas that the data is a string. This can be done by adding the quotechar parameter!

```py
import pandas

data = pd.read_csv("<youre file>", sed=";", quotechar="'")
```

More information about the read_csv can be found in the pandas docs:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html